# what is hive best suited for

Tags: hadoop, hive

I need daily snapshots from all databases of the enterprise and update hive with it.

In case that is the best approach, how do I approach this? I have used sqoop to manually import data to hive but what do I connect PHP to? Hive or Sqoop?

I understand hive is used for OLAP and not OLTP, but taking snapshots once in a day is what hive would be supporting nicely or I should consider other options like Hbase?

I am open to more suggestions considering that the data is structured for the most part.

Comment: What do you mean by "but what do I connect PHP to? Hive or Sqoop?" . Are you trying to access Hive data by a web application made in PHP?

Comment: @user1314742:That's right. I need to automate the process of importing data from MySQL to Hive everyday.

Comment: I would recommend that you start HiveServer and connect to it from you PHP.